# using physics with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, physics

I want to use physics with Libgdx and followed this tutorial : https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/libgdx-physics 
but that doesn't work because of this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;
```

Later I tried following the explanation here :
http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/
but that doesn't work because of this error :

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I tried using some fixes I found online but nothing worked,

Anyone knows how to fix any of this problems or which working jars to use?

Thank you!

Comment: Didnt have any problem using Box2D on Libgdx on android try to follow this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d

Comment: Does it allow adding physical body of not simple shapes? (like the banana in the first link)

Comment: Your first link is using Box2D too.

Comment: In the first link a physical body is being set to the sprite using a variable of this type : `PEXML`. this variable gets an xml object and sets the physics of the sprite using it

Comment: Libgdx comes with Box2D for 2D physics, your first link shows a example of Box2D so you can do anything it shows.

Comment: I did exactly the same. It worked for the desktop application, but for the android application i got the error i wrote up